ASP. NET Web Api doesn't automatically bind CancellationToken from httpContext.RequestAborted
I have an application where I pass CancellationToken All the way down to db but whenever I close swagger tab my cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested doesn't automatically change to true. I also tried postman and different browsers to trigger it.
I have no idea why this is not working.
I decided to inject IHttpContextAccessor by myself and change state of passed token to cancelled from  _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.RequestAborted.
cancellationToken = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.RequestAborted;
cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

Anyways I wonder what I didn't configured to work it normally.
[HttpPost("loadVacancies")]
public async Task<IActionResult> LoadVacancies(
  AuthApplicationModel authApplicationModel,
  CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  {
    await Mediator.Send(new LoadVacanciesCommand.Command(authApplicationModel), cancellationToken);
    return Ok();
  }

    public sealed class Handler : IRequestHandler<Command, Unit>
    {
        private readonly IHeadHunterClient _headHunterClient; // scoped
        private readonly IVacancyRepository _vacancyRepository;
        private readonly ILogger _logger;
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

        public Handler(
            IHeadHunterClient headHunterClient,
            IVacancyRepository vacancyRepository,
            ILogger<Handler> logger,
            IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            _headHunterClient = headHunterClient;
            _vacancyRepository = vacancyRepository;
            _logger = logger;
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        }

        public async Task<Unit> Handle(Command request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var totalVacancies = (await _vacancyRepository.GetTotalVacanciesAsync(cancellationToken)).Total;

            try
            {
                var tokenAuthorization = await
                    _headHunterClient
                    .AuthorizeAsync(request.AuthApplicationModel, cancellationToken);

                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tokenAuthorization))
                    throw new Exception("Error of authorization");

                var options = new ParallelOptions
                {
                    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10,
                };
                IEnumerable<int> allVacanciesId = Enumerable.Range(totalVacancies, 1370416);
                
                await Parallel.ForEachAsync(allVacanciesId, options, async (vacancyId, cancellationToken) =>
                {
                    cancellationToken = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.RequestAborted;
                    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

                    var vacancy = await _headHunterClient.GetVacancyAsync(vacancyId, tokenAuthorization, cancellationToken);

                    Interlocked.Increment(ref totalVacancies);

                    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(vacancy)) return;

                    await _vacancyRepository.InsertOneAsync(vacancy, cancellationToken);

                    _logger.LogInformation("{VacancyId}", vacancyId);
                });

                return Unit.Value;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var cancelTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
                var token = cancelTokenSource.Token;

                await _vacancyRepository.UpdateTotalVacanciesAsync(totalVacancies, token);

                _logger.LogError(ex, "{Message}", ex.Message);

                return Unit.Value;
            }
        }
    }

